# Magento call child html inside static block

Tags: php, html, xml, magento, account

I am a bit confuse about this. I have

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('accountLinks') ?>
```

under header.phtml. How am i going to call 'accountlinks' inside my new static block in Admin?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First,check any `accountLinks` alias name is exit in layout all xml file.
Suppose

If i found that  `store_language` is exit in page.xml and this called in header.phtml `$this->getChildHtml('store_language')`
;

if i want to call this file any where the used below code

```
 echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('page/switch')
->setTemplate('page/switch/languages.phtml')->toHtml();
```

Same way you need to follow

Answer (score 1):

There is probably a corresponding accountLinks.phtml template file.

You can load this in your static block with:

```
{{block type='core/template' template='path/to/accountLinks.phtml'}}
```

path/to/accountLinks.phtml is the path from app/design/frontend/[packagename]/[themename]/template, e.g.: page/html/header/accountLinks.phtml